# How to get pdf in sales_order_invoice_save_after observer

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I want to fire the `invoice_print` button action in `sales_order_invoice_save_after`  observer pogrammatically. 
That means I want to download the invoice pdf on when i click the submit invoice button instead on click `Print` button in invoice view.

My observer event code is :

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
$pdf->render();
$pdf->save('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf');
```

This code save invoice pdf in magento root folder but I want to download it on my PC.

For using `_prepareDownloadResponse` function my model function code is:

```
require_once('app/code/local/Assel/Sms/controllers/adminhtml/IndexController.php');
$controller         = new Assel_Sms_Adminhtml_IndexController(
                            Mage::app()->getRequest(),
                            Mage::app()->getResponse()
                        );  
$request            = $controller->getRequest();
$response           = $controller->getResponse();
$controller->printAction($invoice_id);
//echo $response;
```

My controller Action is :

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoice_id);
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
            '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

When I `echo $response` then it download pdf on `submit invoice` button but it break invoice page redirection to order view page.

How do I do that?

Comment: A simple redirect to the print controller action from the observer could do the trick, although not sure. You might wanna check that.

Comment: Hello @Prateek, Please see my edited question.

Comment: Function `_prepareDownloadResponse` in class `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` should provide you details about how Magento itself handles file download operations. You can try to do it in Observer or you can return the object to controller and try there. Not sure which approach will work.

Comment: I have called `_prepareDownloadResponse`  function from model class but it does not download pdf.

Comment: No, you shouldn't call that method, that method needs some parameters to begin the download. I meant, take a look into the method, and take the code part you need and then implement that in your own method.

Comment: Check my edited question.

Comment: Yes, it will definitely break the re-direction. I'm not sure if you can actually achieve both, download and re-direction. Download is essentially a completion of a request cycle, so there will be nothing PHP will execute further, not even the re-direction.